# How can I access the data in a promise that is pending?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I am looking to return an array in a promise but it keeps saying promise pending. It is returning promise: fulfilled and promise value: array. I have read the documentation and the thread on here about promises and have tried to use it as a function. I have tried to use async await but nothing seems to be working. I read somewhere that you can store it in a global variable, is that the case. Or is you can't store it in a global variable when you use React, because I am using React. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's my code:

```
const currentSymbol = fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=${key}`)
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((results) => {
        return results.map(result => {
            return result
        })
    })

console.log(currentSymbol)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You have two ways the first one is to wrap your call in an async function to await for the value, the other is to handle the value in your result.map() because how it is a promise when you are logging you value maybe the promise is not resolved yet.

Comment: @IvanLynch How do I handle the value in the result.map() method?

Comment: return results.map(result => {
            //Do domething here
            console.log(result)
})

Comment: const currentSymbol = fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=${key}`)
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((results) => {
        // if you don't want to use another then you don't need to use another return
        console.log(result)
    })

Comment: @Ivan Lynch I've already tried that messages but I still get the same results. It still says promise pending. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: I tried with an example api. Look the example.

const currentSymbol = fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users`)
    .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((results) => {
        console.log(results)
    })

Comment: @IvanLynch That didn't work either.

Comment: You don't see this working? https://jsbin.com/delofam/edit?js,console

Comment: @IvanLynch I'm trying to return the global variable

Answer (score 2):

How about this beautiful [await / async](https://javascript.info/async-await) implementation ?

```
function currentSymbol(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=${key}`)
        .then((res) => {
            resolve( res.json());
        })
    });
}
```

Then get result with:

```
let result = await currentSymbol();
```

The **issue** is that you are logging a `Promise` object which is `awaitable`. To execute the Promise and get its actual result you need to make use of either `.then()` or `await` implementation on the Promise object itself

Comment: Hi, so what was my code doing before even with the implementation of the .then

Comment: when i use the let result = await it says that await can't not be used.

Comment: it says `await` cannot be used most likely because you are not in an `async` context. Please take a look at the link attached in my answer. if you are really forced to use `.then()` implementation, then you need  to do: `currentSymbol().then((result)=> {...Do something with result} )`

Comment: Specifically, if you can't use `await` then you should put `console.log()` and any other logic inside the final `.then() `.

Comment: There is no need to wrap `fetch()` in a manually created promise.  That's an anti-pattern and one of the reasons it's an anti-pattern is that people generally screw up the error handling which you have.  You do not propagate a rejected promise back to the caller.  But, if you just `return fetch(...).then(...)`, that's all you need.  No need to manually wrap in a promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 totally agree. Although the implementation is anti-pattern (because I cheaped on coding time), this snippet of code may actually help OP understand what a Promise really is.

Comment: But, it's a poor recommendation for how to code it.  It's not something you should teach anyone.  You could edit your answer to be a good recommendation to teach.